# Flashing Folder on Mac Pro 1,1 after trying to Bootcamp

Tags: macos, bootcamp, startup, mac-pro

So I bought a Mac 1,1 and it runs great, until I tried to bootcamp it the other day with an old windows HDD i had. I downloaded windows, and tried to bootcamp it and now it will not boot the Mac HDD, but if I hold option on boot the HDD shows up and then i can boot into it. I am on OSX Lion.

Answer (score 1):

You probably killed the boot sector for the OS X.

Use the CMD-R to restore the OSX.

Comment: okay. will that affect the programs i currently have installed or will those be unaffected.

Comment: NOPE, it will only repair the OS X it self, no apps will be impacted.

Comment: also, bootcamp refuses to work with windows 7 32bit on a USB stick. any thoughts?

Comment: sorry, that would be a new question :)

Comment: =P fine. lol ill ask another